# Essential tags for building the java project using maven in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, apache-storm

I am building my java project using maven but couldn't succeed. So, can anyone please tell me the essential tags and their corresponding values required in pom.xml to build a project? Also, how do i add the storm dependencies manually from command line?

My directory structure of project :

```
ROOT
 |
 |----com--->test----->newpackage---->*.class
 |--- META-INF------>MANIFEST.MF
 |----resource----->words.txt
 |----pom.xml
 |-----*.jar
```

Initially i tried [Maven Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency) and create the `pom.xml` like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>com.test.newpackage</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But, after that i use `mvn package`. It throw this exception :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: unknown
POM Location: /home/naresh/Desktop/SharedFolder/StormEclipse/pom.xml

Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/naresh/Desktop/SharedFolder/StormEclipse/pom.xml


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/naresh/Desktop/SharedFolder/StormEclipse/pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/naresh/Desktop/SharedFolder/StormEclipse/pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1599)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:506)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
    ... 12 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 22 14:38:24 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After that i used this link [Maven link 2](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster) and created the pom.xml like this :

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.newpackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>  
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.test.newpackage</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository where we can found the storm dependencies <repository> 
            <id>clojars.org</id> <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url> </repository> -->
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Storm Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This time it throw this exception :

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) storm:storm:jar:0.8.1

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=storm -DartifactId=storm -Dversion=0.8.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=storm -DartifactId=storm -Dversion=0.8.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.test.newpackage:wordcount:jar:0.0.1
    2) storm:storm:jar:0.8.1

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.test.newpackage:wordcount:jar:0.0.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About your structure:

Maven assumes the java classes to be in `src/main/java` and the resources (anything in your folder `resource` and your META-INF dir) in `src/main/resources`. The directory structure you described will not work even if you tweak maven a bit because of the java classes in the root dir (recursion). Why don't you use the default structure? You should really have a good reason to change this.

storm Dependency:

You already have the link to the external repository in your POM. But it is outcommented. This should work as expected. If you are behind a proxy you have to [define a proxy in your settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: After your suggestions i have kept my pom.xml to be like this. Also, I have kept my folder structure as you said. Now i am able to create jar file in target folder. Which only contain the META-INF, but my class files are missing any input? Also i am pasting my pom.xml file <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.test.newpackage</groupId>
 <artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: Could you please add the new structure to your question? I'm not sure if I understand what the actual state is. Please note: The folder `src/main/java` should not contain .class files but the uncompiled .java files. Maven compiles them for you. .class files in this folder will be ignored and will not be added to your jar file!

Answer (score 1):

You should have at least those 3 tags :

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
```

It's the way maven identifies an artifact, using those 3 properties (when you define a dependency).

Answer (score 0):

The most important tags are the ones which are mentioned in the error message:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
```

which you missed in your pom file.

Comment: I have pasted the whole error in my question at the last. Also, please check my directory structure at the top of my question. Is there a problem if i use in this way?

Comment: you are not following the [default Maven layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) you should follow that.