# ClassNotFoundException in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, morphia

I'm getting problems when using a dependency from my Tomcat web application.  I've tried:

1. Adding the .jar to WEB-INF/lib
2. Adding the path in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties
3. Adding the .jar in my Tomcat configuration in in IntelliJ
4. Adding the .jar to $TOMCAT_HOME/lib

However, I get the same error when the dependency is called:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    com.turn.quest.mongo.MongoManager.<init>(MongoManager.java:31)
    com.turn.quest.mongo.MongoManager.<clinit>(MongoManager.java:22)
    com.turn.quest.mongo.data.Document.<init>(Document.java:30)
    com.turn.quest.mongo.data.Template.<init>(Template.java:21)
    com.turn.quest.mongo.data.GeoTargetingTemplate.<init>(GeoTargetingTemplate.java:15)
    com.turn.jaxrs.template.TemplateController.get(TemplateController.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:168)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:280)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1341)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1273)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1223)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1213)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
    com.turn.quest.filters.ClickjackFilter.doFilter(ClickjackFilter.java:27)
    com.turn.quest.filters.PbAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(PbAuthenticationFilter.java:286)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy315.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

If I call the dependency from outside Tomcat, everything works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add it as a dependency to your IDEA project definition. If you are using maven or gradle, add the dependency to your build file. For example, for maven, you would add the following to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>0.109</version>
</dependency>
```

If you configured your project through IDEA:

1. Go to `File > Project Structure`
2. Click on the *Modules* link in the *Project Settings* section on the left.
3. Select the module that uses the dependency.
4. Click on the *Dependencies* tab.
5. Click the add button [image] on the right and select "Library"
6. In the "Choose Libraries" dialog, click the "New Library..." button and select Java from the popup list
7. In the File Browswer dialog, select the JAR file(s) for the library, or the directory containing the JAR files (it will add all JARs in the directory), or the directory containing the classes.
8. Click OK on the file chooser dialog
9. In the "Configure Library" dialog, give the Library an appropriate name. You can add sources and javadocs to the definition if desired. (You can also do that in the File Chooser form the previous steps by selecting multiple JARs. IDEA automatically determines if they are classes, sources, or Javadoc.)
10. Click OK on the "Configure Library" dialog.
11. Back in the "Choose Libraries" dialog, the library you just created should be selected. (If not, select it.) Click the "Add Selected" button
12. Click OK on the Project Structure dialog.

For more detail, see the "Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries" in the Help Guide (also on the [web here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html?search=Configuring%20Module%20Dependencies%20and%20Libraries)).

Now when you deploy your Web app to Tomcat via an IDEA Tomcat run/debug configuration, the library will be deployed along with the rest of your code. See the "Run/Debug Configuration: Tomcat" topic in the IDEA help guide (or on the [web here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html?search=Run/Debug%20Configuration:%20Tomcat)) for more information.

Comment: The dependency is already in my project definition.  It's weird because I can use the dependency outside Tomcat just fine, but it  throws the error when contained in a Tomcat servlet.

Comment: Correction, I just noticed that the error switched to "NoClassDefFoundError" for my dependency

Answer (score 1):

The above error implies jar containing class org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia is not present in the class path. So make sure in your web application's lib or tomcat's lib contains the jar containing the above class. I think you can get the jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.morphia).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42824675/2538853

This is due to Morphia jar not being part of your output war/jar. Eclipse or local build includes them as part of classpath, but remote builds or auto/scheduled build don't consider them part of classpath.

You can include dependent jars using plugin.

Add below snippet into your pom's plugins section

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```