# How to work with MAVEN and SBT in two different projects?

Tags: maven, playframework, sbt

I'm working in a project that uses `MAVEN`. And another project which uses `Play Framework` and `SBT`, this uses the first project as dependency. But how can I resolve the dependencies of the first project into the second project ? Since that SBT doesn't read `pom.xml` natively. And how to make this maintainable ? I mean, I don't want to have to maintain two different files all the time, I want to this integration to be smooth.

**My current approach**

I'm cloning/pulling the first project, resolving its dependencies with maven, as I normally would do it with maven, right ? Also I'm getting my first project as dependency from Amazon S3 with [aws-maven](https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven).
And then I just set in my second project to [use my local maven repository](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html).
Is this a good approach ? I think it is because I can combine the best of two technologies. But I might missing some point here. Please advice.

I tried to use some plugins ([1](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader),[2](https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin)) from sbt to read my `pom.xml` file but I have faced several issues ([1](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader/issues/20),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)) which makes me to give up trying to use them and go forward with a more *native* solution.

What do you guys think ? Any suggestion or advice ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you publish your first project to S3, you might want to use this plugin for your second project: https://github.com/ohnosequences/sbt-s3-resolver
Which do the same thing as the aws-maven plugin. So you can get the first project as dependency of the second project and be able to work with them on other environment as well.