# a maven program is able to run successfully from eclipse but not from command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project in eclipse and I'm able to run this successfully through eclipse. However, when I execute `mvn install` and create a jar and then run this jar, I get below exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder

I have added all the needed dependencies in my pom.xml file. below the content of pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tatacommunications.spotlight</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceAnalysis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.tatacommunications.spotlight.ServiceAnalysis</mainClass>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.tatacommunications.spotlight.ServiceAnalysis</mainClass>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-    common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-   client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m04</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-   simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The dependencies need to provided into classpath because Maven doesn't bundle dependencies. More information you can find here. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)

Comment: Do you understand what the exception means?

Comment: How are you running you JAR? When you are running your Jar, where is the folder in which all the dependencies are?