# ClassNotFoundException on using Tez for Hive

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I got the below error :

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/runtime/api/Event
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:266)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:252)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:309)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:434)
>         at HiveRead.(HiveRead.java:37)
>         at HiveRead.main(HiveRead.java:24)
>       Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/tez/runtime/api/Event
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:225)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:276)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:324)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:499)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:486)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:506)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1437)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1422)
>         at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
>         at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
>         at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/runtime/api/Event
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TezCompiler.runStatsDependentOptimizations(TezCompiler.java:282)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TezCompiler.optimizeOperatorPlan(TezCompiler.java:133)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TaskCompiler.compile(TaskCompiler.java:134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10947)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:246)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:250)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:477)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1242)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1229)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:191)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tez.runtime.api.Event
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 25 more
>       org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/runtime/api/Event
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:266)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:252)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:309)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
>         at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:434)
>         at HiveRead.(HiveRead.java:45)
>         at HiveRead.main(HiveRead.java:24)
>       Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/tez/runtime/api/Event
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:225)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:276)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:324)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:499)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:486)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:506)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1437)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1422)
>         at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
>         at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
>         at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/runtime/api/Event
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TezCompiler.runStatsDependentOptimizations(TezCompiler.java:282)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TezCompiler.optimizeOperatorPlan(TezCompiler.java:133)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TaskCompiler.compile(TaskCompiler.java:134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10947)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:246)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:250)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:477)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1242)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1229)
>         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:191)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tez.runtime.api.Event
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 25 more

I want to use `Tez` for hive instead of `mr`. I changed `hive.execution.engine` to `tez` in `hive-site.xml` and run hiveserver2 .
I am using Hive Java API to run Hive queries and when I run queries using Tez, I get that error. I am using Maven to get all required jars and I have 
`tez jar`, `tez commons`, 'tez runtime api`.I am also following [this tutorial](http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap-tez-configure_hive_for_tez.html) to configure tez

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency  : Look at the second answer here. You might need to use maven-shade plugin to build the uber-jar. Or provide the jar on the classpath.