# Spring cloud config example from spring.io not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to implement the example shown in [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

about Spring Cloud centralized configuration, but when it comes to start the server, there is a weird compilation error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/AbstractHealthIndicator
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at com.example.cloud.demoCloudConfig.DemoCloudConfigApplication.main(DemoCloudConfigApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
... 35 common frames omitted
```

The pom.xml and the @SpringBootClasses, the application.properties are the same of the link I've provided, so see this link:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

What kind of problem can it be?

Comment: do you have this line in application.properties `management.security.enabled=false`? which version of springboot are u using?

Comment: Hi, I've set it in the server but nothing different happens. I'm using 1.5.9 RELEASE

Comment: I just checked out the project and went into the complete section and everything worked fine for me. My guess is corrupt maven cache in ~/.m2/repository

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following dependency in ur maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

If it exists, Please check the maven configuration properly in place in eclipse.
[NoClassDefFoundError on Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)

Comment: Thanks, there was not in the server but when added gives the same problem.

Comment: Please try building outside eclipse, see the link mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the version of the libraries.
Considering that even the Official Spring tutorial doesn't work on my computer, it is really a problem of incompatibility (or with my system) or among the libraries.

Apparently the version 1.5.9.RELEASE exposed in the spring example doesn't work correctly.

I've tried cloning also the github repository of the example getting the same compilation error.

In this specific case, switching to version 1.5.5.RELEASE solved the problem.