# org.json dependency with Maven gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, json, maven

I am using Maven for the first time. 
I want to use [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180130%20org.json) and I have added the dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Running `mvn package` works fine. 
 
When trying to execute, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
```

I have tried to change the scope and double check API-documentation/xml-tags.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10569417/8543529) solved it for me :-)

Comment: How do you package your application? As JAR/WAR/EAR? How are you running your code?

Comment: I package it as .jar. I am running in terminal using java -cp to/jar package.mainClass. 
Solved by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10569417/8543529

Answer (score 2):

Try last version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Import Changes.

And do:

```
mvn clean && mvn install
```

Comment: This did not work, but thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: Check imports.
Recreate project as maven.
Be sure that imports updates after pom.xml changes.