# I am getting this exception "org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/MavenInvocationException" when I try executing jar file from command prompt

Tags: maven, jar

I have a maven project selenium webdriver test cases, for which I am able to create a jar file but when I try executing in command prompt I get this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/MavenInvocationException exception.

Comment: [I was not packaging the jar file with all the dependenciesSolution is to use a plugin to package all your dependencies within run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a repository corruption.
Try deleting org/apache/maven folder in your .m2 repository and try again