# NoClassDefFoundError on runtime Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use the dependency Ipregistry for my Maven project but when I run the jar using the command `java -jar RandomChat-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, it prints out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: co/ipregistry/api/client/cache/IpregistryCache
        at fr.randomcodes.randomchat.server.ServerMain.<init>(ServerMain.java:10)
        at fr.randomcodes.randomchat.server.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.ipregistry.api.client.cache.IpregistryCache
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 2 more
```

I use the commands `mvn clean package` and `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="fr.randomcodes.randomchat.server.ServerMain" -s "E:\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\conf\settings.xml"` to compile my project. I don't seem to have any problem while compiling the project, I only have errors at runtime.
Here is my pom.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr.randomcodes.randomchat</groupId>
  <artifactId>RandomChat</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RandomChat</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>co.ipregistry</groupId>
      <artifactId>ipregistry-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>fr.randomcodes.randomchat.server.ServerMain</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>fr.randomcodes.randomchat.server.ServerMain</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I spent the whole day trying to find a solution, so thank you very much for anwsering!

Comment: Check this solution (using of the `maven-shade-plugin`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency

Comment: Do you need to use all three plugins? maven-assembly-plugin is best.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much! (I already saw that post but I didn't scroll down enough to see the solution... thanks!)