# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser

Tags: java, maven-plugin, executable-jar

[image]

I created the `JAR` file with `Maven`, after running it with the `java -jar` command, it throws me an exception:

```
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser)
```

Reading on the forums the problem lies in the `classpath`, the `Jar` does not recognize `Maven` dependencies.

I really don't know how to do it, can someone help me, please?

Comment: You must add a plugin to do that. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-runnable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) topic.

Comment: This might also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency
Seems like the JCalender dependency was not compiled or was removed from the generated.
Could you add the command you used to create your jar with maven?